Wood Pellet Stove Air Intake
I've moved into a house with a wood pellet fireplace. It has a fresh air intake, but the intake isn't connected to any piping - it draws air in from the surrounding room, which in turn draws air in through small cracks in the house. I think it is dragging cold air across my house, making the floor feel cold.
Is it worth installing piping from the outside of my house to the interior where the pellet stove is?
This is my stove: https://enviro.com/products/catalogue/product/?prod=M55CI
And the manual is here: https://enviro.com/media/manuals/?prod=M55CI

It should help a bit, but maybe not enough to keep your feet warm.  It might make you think about sealing up the drafts to help more.  Depending on the house, sealing drafts and adding proper insulation can sometimes save 1/4 to 1/2 of a years fuel use, plus adding comfort.

I have a new pellet stove and it has the fresh air intake, for the combustion process,  fitted and it is well worth doing.

@SolarMike  Having the fresh air intake outside or inside is almost a coin flip for older drafty houses, but needed outside for newer well sealed houses.

@crip659 or those older properties where the insulation etc has been improved.
